# Perl format doesnt use declared variables

Tags: perl, format

I am new to perl and am trying to to format a file. the output only produces the format as it is type not with the scalar values. I am not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for helping.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print "1\a";
my $a = <STDIN>;
print "2\a";
my $b = <STDIN>;
print "3\a";
my $c = <STDIN>;

open DB, ">/perl/folder/data.txt" or die ('1');
format DB = 
%%%%%%%%%%%
$a
$b
$c
%%%%%%%%%%%
.

write DB;
close DB;
```

Comment: You don't have any format specifiers in your format.  Please show us what output you expect given what input (and perhaps drop the extraneous <STDIN> bits all together).

Comment: Sounds like an [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/256831).  Don't use [`formats`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html), not even [`Perl6::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form).  Just use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) if you need formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Miller pointed out, don't use formats. It's a really bad practice.

See [perldoc perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) foi how formats are specified. As pilcrow pointed out, you didn't specify any records.

Here is an example with three left aligned records with the fixed width of 6 characters.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "1\a";
my $a = <STDIN>;
print "2\a";
my $b = <STDIN>;
print "3\a";
my $c = <STDIN>;

my $out_fn = 'formated.txt';
open DB, '>', $out_fn or die "could not open $out_fn: $!";
format DB = 
%%%%%%%%%%%
@<<<<<<
$a
@<<<<<<
$b
@<<<<<<
$c
%%%%%%%%%%%
.

write DB;
close DB;
```

Comment: I am having a hard time producing the 'format' i want with sprintf.  Im assuming this just because being new and not understanding sucks. but it seams that alot of best practices are to do with the appearance of the code and not with actual performance.